# Watson Conversation_Error in Environment Variable

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to copy Watson conversation simple node js application from GitHub (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple) and running in my local.
I have created service key and setup workspace. Next I have updated Workspace ID, User ID & Password in .env, app.js file. I have imported existing car_workspace.json file only and used corresponding Workspace ID.
While running in local host I am getting "The app has not been configured with a  environment variable."
Please help me to understand if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `.env` file and make sure the are no spaces between `=` and the end of the line.

You need to have one file called `.env`, within the project from IBM Developers has one example, just delete the word: example, and the file will called just with `.env` in your Directory, like this image:

[image]

And replace the values with your Service Credentials and your Workspace_id

```
# Environment variables
WORKSPACE_ID=490a9b3b-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
CONVERSATION_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-e1ebbc10
CONVERSATION_PASSWORD=Bxxxx6FdzXxL
```

**Check another format:**

```
USERNAME="yourUsername"
```

And in your `app.js`:

```
var workspace = process.env.WORKSPACE_ID || '<workspace-id>';
console.log(process.env.WORKSPACE_ID);//your value will appear
```

If you want, has another form, you can set the [workspace_id](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L41) and [username](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L41), [password](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L41) in your **app.js** file.

```
var username = 'usernameServiceCredentials'
var password = 'passwordServiceCredentials'
var workspace_id = 'workspaceFromConversation'
```

- See the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) documentation for more information.
- You can see your Credentials inside your **Workspace -> Deploy -> Credentials**