# IBM Watson Conversation Web App Deployment

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

I have been trying for a while to deploy my IBM conversation to bluemix but I can't seem to be able to deploy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple use the [Deploy](https://bluemix.net/deploy?repository=https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple) function available on Bluemix with the url + github repository URL.

This project is web-based from IBM Professionals, they build one example in Node.js using Watson Conversation.

**Note.:** For use your bot, you need to [set](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple#importing-the-conversation-workspace) the `WORKSPACE_ID`, and the **Service Credentials** from your service, and set on the variable `CONVERSATION_USERNAME`, and `CONVERSATION_PASSWORD` in the `.env` file.

If you have problem when you try to set your Service Credentials and your Workspace, you can see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105894/watson-conversation-error-in-environment-variable/46106122#46106122) for using Dotenv and `.env` files.

- The link for the project is: [conversation-simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple).
- Official [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html) using Watson Conversation.