# Creating a webpage containing Watson Conversation using Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm working on creating a simple web page that will contain an instance of an IBM Watson Conversation Chat Bot. I have the following Node.js code that interacts with the IBM cloud and receives the Chat Bot's dialog as console output, and allows the user to respond.

```
var ConversationV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/conversation/v1');

// Set up Conversation service wrapper.
var conversation = new ConversationV1({
  username: 'Security Credentials', // replace with service username
  password: 'Security Credentials', // replace with service password
  version_date: '2018-02-05'
});

var workspace_id = 'Security Credentials'; // replace with workspace ID


// Start conversation with empty message.
conversation.message({
  workspace_id: workspace_id
  }, processResponse);

// Process the conversation response.
function processResponse(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err); // something went wrong
    return;
  }

  // If an intent was detected, log it out to the console.
  if (response.intents.length > 0) {
    console.log('Detected intent: #' + response.intents[0].intent);
  }

  // Display the output from dialog, if any.
  if (response.output.text.length != 0) {
      console.log(response.output.text[0]);
  }

  // Prompt for the next round of input.
    var newMessageFromUser = prompt('>> ');
    // Send back the context to maintain state.
    conversation.message({
      workspace_id: workspace_id,
      input: { text: newMessageFromUser },
      context : response.context,
    }, processResponse)
}
```

I'm not very familiar with web development, and I'm not sure how to create a html page that interacts with Node.js. Ideally I'd like the page to have window that displays the chat bot, as well as having a few images on the page.

I've tried using a few things like Browserify, 
but I'm unsure of where to go next.

Comment: What steps have you followed from the Watson conversation GH repo's README here?
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple

Comment: I've added my security credentials for the appropriate Watson Conversation work space into the apps .env folder, so I'm not sure where the authentication failure is occurring.

Comment: Note, the credentials that you need to use is in the Service credentials on your Conversation service. You need to make sure your env file looks like exactly name: `.env`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105894/watson-conversation-error-in-environment-variable/46106122#46106122) to check details.